# Imprimir N copias de un PDF en 1 hoja con Dompdf en laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, dompdf

Hola amigos actualmente tengo el sigueinte PDF

```
  $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.archivo', $data)->setPaper([0, 0, 340.157,  595,276]);
   return $pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');
```

Estoy usando la libreria Dompdf el mismo se genera correctamente con el tamaño descrito en setPaper, el tema es que quiero 3 copias en 1 sola hoja? si me pudieran guiar
Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Answer (score 0):

en ese `$data` debe ser un array con la cantidad de datos que quieres imprimir

```
$data = [
 $facturas,
 $facturas,
 $facturas'
];
```

ó

```
$CANTIDAD_IMPRIMIR = 3;    
$data = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $CANTIDAD_IMPRIMIR; $i++;){
       array_push($data,'valor'.$i);// asi sera exactamente el mismo que arriba
    };
```

y al final

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.archivo', $data)->setPaper([0, 0, 340.157,  595,276]);
   return $pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, esa variable $nuevoValor que significa? aplique lo que comentas pero no generó cambios

Comment: hola, la variable $nuevoValor la puedes reemplazar o le puedes asignar el valor que deseas imprimir, de cualquier manera ya la edito para que se entienda un poco mas

Comment: Gracias nuevamente yo tengo en $data[ 'facturas'=>$facturas] que es la que paso para traer las variables al pdf tu me propones que cree un nuevo $data?, no comprendo bien lo que comentas, yo lo hice como lo comentaste pero en data dejé mi variable factura únicamente, allí tengo que agregar un valor=>3 después de facturas?

Comment: volvi a editar amigo, trata de tomar el primer ejemplo de $data, recuerda para imprimir varias veces en el mismo PDF $data debe ser un array el segundo ejemplo es para que sea dinamico de cuantas veces lo quieras imprimir

Comment: No comprendo bien tu respuesta, pero gracias por ayudarme, aún sigo buscando la respuesta, saludos